# how to bypass answering machine in twilio

Tags: php, xml, twilio, twilio-twiml

I want to initiate a call from my Twilio number to a customer and say something using the [<Say>](http://twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) verb.

It works fine for me, but some customers have answering machines and they could not pick up the calls and listen to the  verb.

How can I make Twilio bypass the answering machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a parameter for that, but it isn't very reliable.

The parameter is [IfMachine](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#handling-outcomes-answering-machines). Add it to the HTTP POST like this:

```
POST https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/AC123/Calls
IfMachine=true&From=+1XXX&To=+1XXX&Url=http://example.com/twiml
```